# Frame operation xPath locator issues in web bots

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, automation, bots

I was trying iFrame after going through the iFrame chapter but I get error while locating elements after switching to the desired frame. The xPath i am trying is copied from the inspector but still it doesn't work.

**URL:** sample website where there is bot frame

https://www.sbimf.com/en-us

I Am able to click on bot icon and activate the frame. Used the below logic to get all the frames in the page.

```
WebElement bot = driver.findElement(By.className("avaamo__icon"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(bot).perform();
List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println("Frame Size: "+ frames.size());              
for(WebElement frame:frames){
    System.out.println(frame.getAttribute("name"));
}
```

Now that I know the frame 1 is the iframe I am interested, switched to the frame using below. (I am hoping they worked as I don't see any error message).

```
driver.switchTo().frame(1);
//OR
driver.swithTo().frame(avaamoIframe)
```

However, script is failing with unable to find element error, when I tried to access the elements in the frame using the xpath which worked in the browser console.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div[2]/textarea")).sendKeys("Hello");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/a[2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title*='Show me fund details']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("\"//a[contains(text(),'View Fund Details')]\"")).click();
```

Comment: please check the updated post and correct if any changes required.

Comment: can you find a better(more precise) selector for your iframe? I would usually do something like this "driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("myCustomSelector")));"  Also share the html if possible in your question.